# Programmatically read Azure App Insights logs without a client secret?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a C# application that writes traces and exceptions to Azure Application Insights using `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` and the `TelemetryClient` class.

I want to programmatically search the AI trace and exception logs using C#, as opposed to having to use Kusto queries.  Every article I've read on how to do this seems to require that I know the Client Secret for the resource.  But I am unable to obtain this, as I don't have authorization to create certificates and secrets in our environment.  (I do, however, possess the `InstrumentationKey` from the `ApplicationInsights.config` file).

I'm sure there *has* to be a way to do this without using a secret - right?  After all, `TelemetryClient` doesn't require a secret to *write* to AI logs (it just needs the aforementioned `InstrumentationKey`); therefore (since reading is a less risky operation security-wise than writing), I would assume that there's a way to programmatically *read* the logs with just an `InstrumentationKey` and without a client secret.  Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Were you able to find a way?

Comment: Yes, but I had to get a client secret.

Answer (score 4):

Fundamental bad assumption here.

> since reading is a less risky operation security-wise than writing

You are writing logs of application operations that may include security critical information (when URL's get logged, exceptions get logged ,variables are written to the server). So in this case WRITING is NOT critical - you can submit fake data, but that it is.

But READING is security critical because you DO expose legally protected data through reading (i.e. possibly and most likely private information of people).

The rest of your question flows from the assumption reading is less security relevant, so all your conclusions are bad.

This is why you need only an instrumentation key to write, but a client secret to read.

Comment: all correct what you are saying. Maybe just to clarify: To query, you need to have an Azure Active Directory account with the required permissions. How you authenticate using this (client secret or by whatever other means), is not the critical point.

Comment: @TomTom I do in fact have an Azure AD account which is used by the application.  Thus, if I programmatically log into it using OAuth 2.0 with my credentials (account name/password), will this allow me to read the logs?