# Is a new Azure AD Application needed for a secondary application?

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-application-insights

I have a console application that using Application Insights to capture telemetry + logs.
This is running just fine.

Now I am writing another app (a WPF based UI tool) as a way to "monitor" the console application.
I would like this UI to retrieve the app. insights logs and display them with filtering capability.

To do this: Do I need to create another Azure AD Application and register it with app insights? Or can i somehow use the same Azure AD Application that's already been registered for the console app with this new WPF app?

Note: I am using this [article](https://zimmergren.net/retrieve-logs-from-application-insights-programmatically-with-net-core-c/) as a guide.
Here is [another S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621426/programmatically-read-azure-app-insights-logs-without-a-client-secret) that is directly related, but has no answers or hints of any progress.

Comment: It's perfectly fine and doable to use the same app id for all of your apps unless it conflicts with any of your requirements somehow. Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can use the same app registration it really doesn't matter how many apps you use, as long as you're identifying the app properly to the registration through secrets and authentication, i would recommend creating a different secret though for it. just be aware of the caveats, eg, if you have only one app registration, in the enterprise app, you can only set one set of users, so if for example you want to control who has access to one of the apps but not the other. you cant do that through the enterprise application registration. so you would have to do it through your own code. also, api access permissions would apply to both apps. so technically both apps would have access to read insights for example. or whatever other permissions you give the registration. 
just extra considerations like that.

Hope this helps.